# Show Modal prior to stage change

Tags: lightning, opportunity, leads

Looking to validate a proof of concept here. Prior to a user changing the stage of an opp/lead for instance, I want a modal to pop up with a "Please verify X fields before submitting". Rather than a validation rule trip preventing the update, I want to handle the stage change more elegantly. I'm wondering is it possible to handle an event prior to change being made to the stage? Any ideas?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

There's [this idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000Bra7AAC) you could vote on, which really reflects the intent of what you're looking for. The closest thing we have today is the [Path](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=rss_sales_path.htm&type=5), which allows you to set up a field (e.g. Lead Status or Opportunity Stage) that shows up to five fields and some guidance text for each stage as users move from one stage to the next. You can find this under Setup > User Interface > Path Settings.

Answer (score 0):

I think the appexchange component called lightning Popups (made by a company called Stratus360) might do just that. 
I am just about to built a demo around this very same concept: give the rep the chance to fill out the fields before hitting the VRs.
It's free to boot (I am not associated in any shape or form to this company)
https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N3A00000FYDyHUAX

Comment: It seems somewhat clear on phrasing, but could you please **[edit]** your post to explicitly state if you are or are not affiliated with this product so as to conform to our spam policy? Thanks!